# PHP str replace function

Tags: php

I am trying to use `string replace` function in php to remove single and double quotes. Removing single quotes was easy

```
$comment = str_replace("'","",$comment);
```

Please help me with removing double quotes using the similar code line.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php PHP allows quoting strings with either single or double quotes, so just reverse them (though not totally interchangeably in any context)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can quote strings with either single or double quotes. In this case, you want to remove all the double-quotes, so it'd be best to use single-quotes here.

```
$comment = str_replace('"', '', $comment);
```

Pass an array  if you want to remove ***both*** single quotes and double quotes:

```
$comment = str_replace(array("'", '"'), '', $comment);
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to how you replaced `single` quotes:

```
str_replace('"',"",$comment);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $comment = str_replace('"','',$comment);
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can use either " or ' for strings. So you can switch to fit your needs according to the situation.

```
$comment = str_replace('"','',$comment);
```

Comment: Almost do not... Java, C, C++, Objective-C, ... none of them allow. PHP, however, does.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the double quotes:

```
$comment = str_replace("\"","",$comment); 
                        ˆ escape
```

Or you could also use single quotes as the string delimiter:

```
$comment = str_replace('"','',$comment);
```

Note that there are some small diferences using single and double quotes, on this case however, they are the equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$remove[] = "'";
$remove[] = '"';

$comment = str_replace( $remove, "", $comment);
```